# Reading email from gmail is not working

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using Java Mail API along with the following code to read email from my gmail account.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class CheckMails {

   public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
      String password) 
   {
      try {
      Properties properties = new Properties();

      properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
      properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
      Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
      Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

      store.connect(host, user, password);

      //create the folder object and open it
      Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
      emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

      // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
      Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
      System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

      for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
         Message message = messages[i];
         System.out.println("---------------------------------");
         System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
         System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
         System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
         System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

      }

      //close the store and folder objects
      emailFolder.close(false);
      store.close();

      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String mailStoreType = "pop3";
      String username = "myemai@gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String password = "*******";// change accordingly

      check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

   }

}
```

But I am getting the following exceptions:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTH] Web login required: `    https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754`
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:209)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at CheckMails.check(CheckMails.java:26)
at CheckMails.main(CheckMails.java:66)
```

But i have recieved an email from gmail in my inbox which is saying that 
"We recently blocked-in a sign in attempt to your Google Account".
How can i make the program to work properly?

Comment: what part of error message is unclear? have your read google's FAQ?

Comment: Actually The sign in attempt is probably being occur. Otherwise I wouldn't receive the email from google regarding the blockage of sign in attempt. But why its being blocked? Do i need to do any more authentication? Thats not clear to me

Comment: Dude - it looks like you copied your code from [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_authentication.htm).  And you either forgot - or deliberately chose - to add `new javax.mail.Authenticator() ` (?!?).  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Look at my link.  2) Look at Neeraj Jain's post.  3) If it works, please be sure to "upvote" and "accept" Neeraj Jain's response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change Your `emailSession` variable with

```
Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
    }
});
```

As said by Gmail

> Some apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology, which makes
>   your account more vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps,
>   which we recommend, or turn on access if you want to use them despite
>   the risks. Learn more

Just click below link and disable Gmail security settings.It will work.

[Disable Security settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Here is a nice article about [Password Authentication  in Java Mail Api](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javamail-api/9781449367237/ch04.html)