# Searching emails from gmail is not working

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I followed this: [Reading email from gmail is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417037/reading-email-from-gmail-is-not-working) and I am able to fetch all email messages. However, when I use search parameters, I always get 0 results. This is what I tried:

```
  Date d1 = new DateTime(date.getTime()).toLocalDate().toDate();
  Date d2 = new DateTime(date.getTime()).plusDays(-30).toLocalDate().toDate();
  SearchTerm olderThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, d1);
  SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, d2);
  SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(olderThan, newerThan);

  Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(andTerm);
```

If I change the last line to

```
  Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
```

everything works fine and I get all emails. There are emails in my inbox received in the last 30 days. Is there something wrong with my search logic?

Comment: I got this working by changing ReceivedDateTerm to SentDateTerm.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing below line of code, you have to override `match` method and put condition there

```
    // creates a search criterion
    SearchTerm searchCondition = new SearchTerm() {
        @Override
        public boolean match(Message message) {
            try {
                if (message.getSubject().contains(keyword)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    // performs search through the folder
    Message[] foundMessages = folderInbox.search(searchCondition);

    for (int i = 0; i < foundMessages.length; i++) {
        Message message = foundMessages[i];
        String subject = message.getSubject();
        System.out.println("Found message #" + i + ": " + subject);
    }
```

**EDIT :-**

```
SearchTerm andTerm = null;
andTerm = new AndTerm(andTerm, olderThan);  //concat the search terms
andTerm = new AndTerm(andTerm, newerThan );
Message messages[] = folderInbox.search(andTerm);    //search on the imap server
```

**EDIT 1 :-**

```
for (Message message : messages) {
    if (message.getSentDate().after(olderThan) && message.getSentDate().before(newerThan))
       {
          //do whatever you want with your filtered by period message
       } 
}
```

Comment: This didn't change anything, same results. any other pointers?

Comment: Try to search on keyword and tell me if you get result ot not?

Comment: @Jayz please try edited code and tell me the result.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when you do this search?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, the first edited code doesn't work, throws null pointer because this line "andTerm = new AndTerm(andTerm, olderThan);" has andTerm as null from 1st line.   Second edited code obviously works, as it filters out after getting all messages but I guess that is very inefficient.

Comment: After some trial and error, I found out that it works if I change ReceivedDateTerm to SentDateTerm. weird! Just not getting forwarded messages, even without the SearchTerm. Thx for your help.

Comment: I didnot tried the code may be some exception please change the code in answer so it will help to others